# Do I have to watch Star Trek TV and movie series before watching Star Trek Beyond?

Tags: star-trek, suggested-order, star-trek-beyond

There have been many Star Trek movies as well as TV series and I didn't watch any of them. So, do I have to watch complete or any Star Trek TV and movie series to watch ***Star Trek Beyond*** or just the last two movies (***Star Trek*** and ***Star Trek into Darkness***) in order to understand plot points?

Comment: If you want to watch *all* the TV series, that's close to 600 hours. If you watch 10 hours / day, that's around 2 months.

Comment: It can also be completed before 1 year, watching 2 hrs a day. However, I just wanted to know if I have to watch complete series. If it was yes, I would have skipped this new movie.

Comment: @rjmunro challenge accepted... :-)

Comment: @rjmunro 10 hours a day? Slacker.

Comment: J.J. Abrams, the creator of the new movies (starting with *Star Trek*) is on record as not liking the rest of Star Trek. You might actually be *better off* not watching them, as far as he's concerned--though I'm sure there are many Star Trek fans who'd say you're better off skipping Abrams' work and watching "real" Star Trek!

Comment: @KyleStrand - My understanding is that Abrams had little involvement with this one; he was too busy working on Star Wars VII to do very much.

Comment: Nope, just the Fast & Furious movies.  They said "Fast 8" was going to be different without Brian, but this was way different than I was expecting! ;)

Comment: @Jules Ah, you're right. Still, it's in the "Abramsverse". And, heck, some (most?) of the classic movies work on their own anyway; I loved *Wrath of Kahn* without having seen *Space Seed*, much less *The Motion Picture*.

Comment: If you watch the old stuff and like it very much, you will likely be very disappointed by the reboot .. so you might be better of by not knowing that there were movies and shows before - then you are better entertained.
(I personally would recommend watching the old stuff and NOT the new movies if you have the time ...)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In the end it is really up to you. To understand and enjoy the story, all you need are the recent two movies (I'd say).

If you want to understand and notice parallels, nods to the original series, etc. you'd have to watch that as well (including the movies).

But besides that, they did a pretty good job to establish characters, setting etc. without forcing the audience to know everything from past installments.

The only direct canonical reference to the old series is essentially the overall setting (reintroduced) and old Spock in the first *Star Trek* reboot movie from 2009, but that's it. *The Original Series*, *The Next Generation* etc. they all didn't happen in this timeline (except *Enterprise*).

Comment: Don't forget First Contact!

Comment: @Aron, First Contact still happened, but _Star Trek:First Contact_ didn't.

Answer (score 13):

Just watch [Star Trek (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)) and [Star Trek into Darkness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_Into_Darkness).

[Star Trek (2009)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film)) is [kind of a reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek_(film_series)#Reboot_films). It takes place in an alternate reality to the previous films and TV series. There are nods to previous films; like old Spock etc. but they are self explained in the film.

You can still watch the old stuff but they are not compulsory to watch for understanding Star Trek Beyond.

Comment: The 2009 movie (haven't seen the others) draws part of its fun from the tension when things at first don't go the expected way for the main characters and their relations as we know them so well from the series. I'd recommend to just watch a few episodes to become familiar with the original setting.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider - good point.  Plus "Into Darkness" directly references a couple of earlier stories (the TV episode "Space Seed" and the movie "The Wrath of Khan") in such a way that I think it's better to have seen the originals before watching it.

Comment: It only "references" them if you mean "uses the same names for entirely new and different characters". There are no plot connections; the events of Vspace Seed" and "Wrath of Khan" never happen in nuTrek.

Comment: What if you have seen Star Trek (2009) but NOT Star Trek Into Darkness (2013)?  Does this film require having seen Into Darkness?

Answer (score 3):

The movies tend to be fairly self contained, so it is not necessary to "catch up" with the entire Star Trek Universe.  The new movies are a reboot of the original Star Trek storyline anyway, so what happened in the original series may not be relevant to the new movie.